# How to turn Everything Website Right to Left for Arabic Language including JS scripts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have lot of scripts, Dynamic timeline, lot of absolute positioned elements, and all that has to be aligned Right to left, does anyone have experience with this, i wish i can just turn monitor to the wall :D

Comment: With CSS: `direction` https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/direction

Comment: I wouldn't mark this as a duplicate. The way I understand is that he's talking about RTL language website. In that case, the language direction should be set in the html itself too. for example <html dir="RTL">

Comment: I found questions that are about this topic, but as you see in this one I'm trying to find some different approach because it will take a lot of time to change everything, I have 2k lines of HTML.... and 1.5k lines of JS.

Answer (score 3):

If absolute element with coordonates are involved direction won't help much.

You can give a try to a dirty trick.

test in your page :

```
body:hover {
  transform:scale(-1,1)
}
body:hover >* {
  transform:scale(-1,1)
}
```

But, this is morelike a blister than a clean way to do it :(

if that's fine with you, then do:

```
body, body>* {/* turns monitor to the wall :) */
  transform:scale(-1,1)
}
```

You can  of course involve `direction` if the page language is not seen or declared properly.

```
body>* {direction:rtl;}
```

Comment: I like this answer, its awesome idea, but in this case it wont help, on the other way, it's risky to do this on this website because of clients.

Comment: @Marko.dev i agree, transform will only mirror the layout but won't fix anything. direction should apply itself from language :( .

Answer (score 0):

With css:

```css
div {
        direction: rtl;
    }
```

```html
<div> Hello World! </div>
```